# C# optional parameter not properly mapped with json data of Ajax(with same name of different types)

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, optional-parameters

json data Parameters of ajax not matching properly for optional parameter of c# method

```
$.ajax({
                        url: '/CusotmerManagement/Cusotmer/GetCusotmerByDisplayId/',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: {
                            displayId: selectedCustomerRow.DisplayId,
                            transportationModeName: selectedCustomerRow.TransportationModeName,
                            jagurRef: jaguarDetails                                                           
                        },
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {
                            //some code
                        }
                    });
```

In the above ajax call i have *omitted optional parameter* (class CustomerSelectorResult ) and im passing all other parameter importantly  **displayId**(of primary customer).Since i dont have secondary customer i omitted CustomerSelectorResult(***Note :CustomerSelectorResult also have DisplayId*** )

**C# method**

```
    public JsonResult GetCusotmerByDisplayId(string displayId, string transportationModeName, int jagurRef, CustomerSelectorResult alternatePickUpCarrier = null)
     {
           //my logic
     }
```

But in c# method displayId and DisplayId which is present inside CustomerSelectorResult  have same values even though CustomerSelectorResult   is optional parameter.

**CustomerSelectorResult class**

```
public class CustomerSelectorResult 
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string DisplayId { get; set; }//note display id within CustomerSelectorResult 
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
        public AddressResult Address { get; set; }
     }
```

**Why DisplayId of optional parameter takes values from main parameter(displayId)??**

Note: I overcame this problem by explicitly pass the value as CustomerSelectorResult : null[image].

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All this magic is called MVC model binding. 
If `CustomerSelectorResult` is not null in your request then default model binding will try to construct it from your request and will find `displayId` in your request.

[MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx)

Please try this solution. It's not the best but it will solve your problem.
Create new class derived from `DefaultModelBinder`

```
public class CustomerSelectorResultModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var data = base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);

        var model = data as CustomerSelectorResult;
        //check if CustomerSelectorResult's all properties are null except DisplayId.
        if(model != null &&
           model.Name == null &&
           model.RoleId == default(int) &&
           model.RoleName == null &&
           model.Address == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return data;
    }
}
```

And apply this class on your action

```
public JsonResult GetCusotmerByDisplayId(string displayId, string transportationModeName, int jagurRef, [ModelBinder(typeof(CustomerSelectorResultModelBinder))]CustomerSelectorResult alternatePickUpCarrier = null)
     {
           //my logic
     }
```

Comment: can't we have optional parameter value as null in my case?

Comment: @ManirajSS please look at my solution. Say if something is wrong.